# How can i restrict unauthenticated access to Firebase Firestore while permitting new users to add account data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firebase authentication on my reactJS application.
When a user signs up, an entry is added into firestore to store some account details at user/(UID).

I need to create firestore rules that willL

1. Prevent unauthenticated users from reading and writing to firestore
2. Only allow users to read their own data in firestore Users/(users UID)
3. Allow newly registered users to write to firestore so data can be added for their account.

I have tried the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But i am receiving an email each day from Firebase saying my rules are insecure and anyone can write to my database.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) (`/{document=**}`) with the rule `allow write: if request.auth != null;` which allows any authenticated user to write in any collection/document of the database. Based on the given constraint, try refactoring your rules to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{sub=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is giving me the following error when i click my signup button: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: @adminadmin can you share your query and also ensure the user is logged in ?

Comment: user is not logged in, this is for user registration form to create new user